# Get all the elements id after a targeted element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, selectors-api

So how can I get all the elements after a targeted element for example I want to get all the elements after the id call c regardless of the quantity of elements that is after c

For example

```
d
e
f
```

and I want to output the result in a id element call output

This is my code i'm stuck on

```js
/*
Get all the elements ids after the id call c and output those 
ids in the id call output 

For example 
document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = ??;

How?
*/
```

```css
#output{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 id='a' class='letters'>A</h1>
<h1 id='b' class='letters'>B</h1>
<h1 id='c' class='letters'>C</h1>
<h1 id='d' class='letters'>D</h1>
<h1 id='e' class='letters'>E</h1>
<h1 id='f' class='letters'>F</h1>

<h1 id='output'></h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No offense to others examples here but I notice some code examples here will have some compatibility issues on certain browsers like

IE 11 so this works on all the major browsers that I tested this on. Just in case if your trying to get this to work on IE 11 so here is my example...

```js
var afterC = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#c ~ *.letters')).map(function(elem){ return elem.getAttribute('id');});

document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = afterC;
```

```css
#output{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 id='a' class='letters'>A</h1>
<h1 id='b' class='letters'>B</h1>
<h1 id='c' class='letters'>C</h1>
<h1 id='d' class='letters'>D</h1>
<h1 id='e' class='letters'>E</h1>
<h1 id='f' class='letters'>F</h1>

<h1 id='output'></h1>
```

Comment: Thank you every for responding to this post but I feel like Thomas Wayne's method fits my style so thank you Thomas Wayne this solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll('#c ~ .letters')` which uses the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator):

```js
document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('#c ~ .letters')
).map(element => element.textContent).join(' ');
```

```css
#output{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 id='a' class='letters'>A</h1>
<h1 id='b' class='letters'>B</h1>
<h1 id='c' class='letters'>C</h1>
<h1 id='d' class='letters'>D</h1>
<h1 id='e' class='letters'>E</h1>
<h1 id='f' class='letters'>F</h1>

<h1 id='output'></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get c's position, then take all h1s' that are following:

```
 const c = document.querySelector("#c");
 const h1s = [...document.querySelectorAll("h1")];
 const position = h1s.indexOf(c);

 const result = h1s.filter((_, i) => i > position);

  for(const entry of result)
    output.appendChild(entry.cloneNode(true));
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way:

```js
// using a named function, passing in a CSS selector:
let getAllAfter = function(selector) {

  // here we return the result of document.querySelectorAll(),
  // after using Array.from() to convert the Array-like NodeList
  // to an Array:
  return Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll(
      // using the passed-in selector and concatenating that
      // with the general sibling combinator ('~') and, in this
      // case using '.letters' to restrict the selector to elements
      // containing that class:
      selector + '~ .letters')
  );
}

// setting the textContent of the element with the id of 'output'
// to be equal to the Array of elements - having mapped
// their textContent using Array.prototype.map(), and joining
// the resulting Array using Array.prototype.join():
document.getElementById('output').textContent = getAllAfter('#c').map(el => el.textContent).join(', ');
```

```css
#output {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 id='a' class='letters'>A</h1>
<h1 id='b' class='letters'>B</h1>
<h1 id='c' class='letters'>C</h1>
<h1 id='d' class='letters'>D</h1>
<h1 id='e' class='letters'>E</h1>
<h1 id='f' class='letters'>F</h1>

<h1 id='output'></h1>
```

This is, of course, using a hardcoded selector which isn't particularly useful in different contexts, so to modify the above function to accept a second selector, to restrict the selected subsequent siblings to a selector:

```js
// using a named function, passing in a CSS selector:
let getAllAfter = function(targetSelector, siblingSelector) {

  // here we return the result of document.querySelectorAll(),
  // after using Array.from() to convert the Array-like NodeList
  // to an Array:
  return Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll(
      // using the passed-in selector and concatenating that
      // with the general sibling combinator ('~') and, in this
      // case using '.letters' to restrict the selector to elements
      // containing that class:
      targetSelector + ' ~ ' + siblingSelector)
  );
}

// setting the textContent of the element with the id of 'output'
// to be equal to the Array of elements - having mapped
// their textContent using Array.prototype.map(), and joining
// the resulting Array using Array.prototype.join():
document.getElementById('output').textContent = getAllAfter('#c', '.letters').map(el => el.textContent).join(', ');
```

```css
#output {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 id='a' class='letters'>A</h1>
<h1 id='b' class='letters'>B</h1>
<h1 id='c' class='letters'>C</h1>
<h1 id='d' class='letters'>D</h1>
<h1 id='e' class='letters'>E</h1>
<h1 id='f' class='letters'>F</h1>

<h1 id='output'></h1>
```

Of course, in compliant browsers, we could avoid concatenating Strings and simply use a template literal to convert the supplied Strings to a selector:

```js
// using a named function, passing in a CSS selector:
let getAllAfter = function(targetSelector, siblingSelector) {

  // here we return the result of document.querySelectorAll(),
  // after using Array.from() to convert the Array-like NodeList
  // to an Array:
  return Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll(
      // using the passed-in selector and concatenating that
      // with the general sibling combinator ('~') and, in this
      // case using '.letters' to restrict the selector to elements
      // containing that class:
      `${targetSelector} ~ ${siblingSelector}`)
  );
}

// setting the textContent of the element with the id of 'output'
// to be equal to the Array of elements - having mapped
// their textContent using Array.prototype.map(), and joining
// the resulting Array using Array.prototype.join():
document.getElementById('output').textContent = getAllAfter('#c', '.letters').map(el => el.textContent).join(', ');
```

```css
#output {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 id='a' class='letters'>A</h1>
<h1 id='b' class='letters'>B</h1>
<h1 id='c' class='letters'>C</h1>
<h1 id='d' class='letters'>D</h1>
<h1 id='e' class='letters'>E</h1>
<h1 id='f' class='letters'>F</h1>

<h1 id='output'></h1>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [General sibling combinator (`~`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
  - [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).